# How to Query Return Value on using Compact SQL Command?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, winforms

I using a compact database created on visual studio. just for a stand alone system with it's database intact already although i'm stuck here in using a select query that could retrieve a boolean if the user exist on the database and also then return it's ID and Username if the user entry exist. can i ask for help regarding on this one.. I am a student trying to learn c# on using compact database.

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!IsEmpty()) 
            {
                if (!IsLenght()) 
                {
                    using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=" +
                    System.IO.Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), "INCdb.sdf"))) 
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        SqlCeCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM LoginTB Where username=@user1 AND password=@pass1";
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user1", UserTxt.Text.Trim());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass1", PassTxt.Text.Trim());
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                        validlogin = (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                        con.Close();
                        MessageBox.Show(validlogin.ToString());


                        if (validlogin == true) 
                        {
                            // cmd. return value ID
                            // cmd. return value Username
                            //SysMain Mn = new SysMain();
                            //Mn.ShowDialog();
                            //this.Hide();
                        }
                    }                        
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            gbf.msgBox(1, ex.Message.ToString(), "");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What value you try to return exactly on your database? Or just try to check it returns any rows or not to validate your login is successful or not? And do **not** store your passwords as a plain text.

Comment: yes sir i am trying to validate if the data exist on the database and then return the value of it's id and username and logID which is found in the database as one of it's columns.

Comment: `ExecuteScalar` will return the value stored in the first column of the first row of the first result set returned by your query.

Comment: ic.. so i shouldn't have use ExecuteScalar for this one sir Jodrell? i was hoping to have a return boolean value like "true" if the username and password exist in the database "false" if not. but if it was "true" if it pass the 2nd if condition then retrieve it's ID, username, LogID for the specific row found in the Table LoginTB. that i was hoping to be done on this code sir i think i have the wrong one then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below is probably better, unless there is something special and unstated about the schema of `LoginTB`.

```
// ...
var validLogin = false;
using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(
    "Data Source=" +
        System.IO.Path.Combine(
            Path.GetDirectoryName(
                System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location),
    "INCdb.sdf"))) 
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCeCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText =
            "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LoginTB Where username=@user1 AND password=@pass1";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user1", UserTxt.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass1", PassTxt.Text.Trim());
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    validlogin = ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar()) > 0;
}

MessageBox.Show(validlogin.ToString());

// ...
```

Note the use of [`COUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx)

Comment: yes Sir Thanks but how about retrieving some of the column ID, Username, and LogID like using a foreach?

Comment: Well, then you'll need to call `ExecuteReader`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you much sir i've learn i need for this post.. thanks very much also for the link "ExecuteReader".